# Unexpected BPython console output behaviour

Tags: terminal, shell, python, console, stdout

I am using BPython to run Python scripts, and I found the console output has a different behavior than the regular Python console.. For example this small snippet:

```
import time
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("\r{}".format(i), end="")
```

outputs in Python:

```
99                                            |
>>>                                           |
```

but outputs in BPython:

```
26                                            |
51                                            |
75                                            |
99                                            |
>>>                                           |
                                              ^ end of the console
```

These apparently random numbers just depend on my console *width*. I suspect the BPython cursor to be shifted right on each call to `print` even though the string starts with a `\r`. When it reaches the right end of the console, the current line can't be erased anymore and so a new line is started.

Any way of fixing this?

UPDATE: (bug reported [there](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/issues/574))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `bpython-curses` instead if you need this behavior, because (as you have noticed) the standard bpython frontend doesn't deal with this correctly. You're approximately correct in your explanation: bpython is logging the output to a fake sys.stdout and then trying to guess about how to render it. Its guess is very naive, and while it does account for a limited number of terminal formatting escape sequences, it doesn't account for carriage returns. The cursor is moved to a line on the terminal and that calculated line of output is written, resulting in what you see.

Comment: This seems to be what I was needing. Thank you! :)